# Convergence of the reciprocal of a function whose derivative tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, derivatives

If $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = \infty$$ prove that $$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{f(x)}\neq\infty$$
if $f'(x) \geq 1$ and $f(x) \geq1$ for all values of $x$. I'm thinking I can find a way to write it in big O notation to show this, but I have no idea how.

Comment: I don't think the word "ambiguous" means what you think it means.

Comment: Also, I think it's false --- what happens if $f(x)$ is (some simple variation on $x\log x$?

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = \infty$$ is not true for $x\log x$

Comment: $(x\log x)' =( 1+\log x)\ \ {\buildrel{x\rightarrow\infty}\over\rightarrow\ \ \infty}$.

Comment: In addition to David Mitra's observation, the conditions $f'(x), f(x)\geq 1$ are spurious, considering that any nonnegative increasing function can be adjusted via $f(x)+x^2+1$ to satisfy them which will give even more counterexamples.

Comment: @Alex, if you add $x^2+1$, you make the integral of the reciprocal converge.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: whoops, it should instead be something like $+x\log(x)$